# How to reverse(or cancel) OpenGL SRT Transformation with another Transformation?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, transformation

I'm studying for an exam, and a previous exam had this question:

```
1. void drawGLScene(){ 
2. glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

3. glLoadIdentity(); 
4. glTranslatef(0, 1, 0); 
5. glRotatef(-90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
6. glScalef(.5, 2, 1); 
7. drawChevron();  
8. glFlush(); 
9. }
```

"Write three lines of OpenGL that when inserted in between lines 6 and 7 would 
reverse (cancel) the effect of the transformations implemented by lines 4 to 6. Do 
not use glLoadIdentity()."

I'm pretty sure it has to be another Translate, Rotate, Scale. But I know it isn't as simple as just using what I think are the reverse parameters. I'm having a lot of trouble understanding which way the x and y axes are facing, and whether scale effects the translation.

Would anyone be able to explain to me how to correctly do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three lines would be:

```
glScalef(1.0/.5, 1.0/2, 1.0/1);
glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(0, -1, 0);
```

Basically you need to perform inverse transformations in reverse order. You start with scaling. Inverse for scaling would be to scale back but this time with 1/factor. Then you rotate it back by 90 degrees and translate back 1 unit on y axis.

Comment: Okay, see I would have said:

glTranslatef(0, -1, 0);
glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glScalef(2, 0.5, 1.0/1);

at first. Can you explain to me why that's wrong and why yours is right? I know you're right but I don't know why :P

Comment: Take some object into your hand. Move it and then rotate. Afterward just think what you need to do to get this object to start position. Got it?

Comment: Draw it. I am not kidding. Just take a simple 2d example. A triangle or something. And then draw it. Translate, rotate, scale. And then see what happens if you apply your transformations to get back to the original.